# В Unity у OnClick кнопки не отображается моя функция RestartLevel()

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я начинающий разработчик игр на Unity 2d.
При создании кнопки рестарта уровня я столкнулся с тем, что в кнопке
во вкладке OnClick ------>scene нет функции RestartLevel()

код для кнопки рестарта:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Scene : MonoBehaviour
{
    void RestartLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

вот скрин:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnDX9.png

платформа ios,
версия юнити 2020.3.7f1 LTS

Comment: ...вот к чему приводит игнорирование явного указания модификаторов доступа...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По дефолту методы приватные. Чтобы он появился в списке, нужно, чтобы метод был публичным.

```
public class Scene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public  void RestartLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```